# Spree Commerce is working, but no assets.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, e-commerce, spree

I'm trying to customize and modify Spree Commerce, but none of the standard asset files/images/views are available under either app/views, lib/assets, or anywhere else I can think to look. I'm trying to go through their tutorials, but I can't find anything to edit. Is there another command I need to decompress everything or something? Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: It depends on how you're running the server. Are you running it in the production environment? Rails has a setting (`config.serve_static_assets`) inside `config/environments/production.rb` that is set to `false`, which means that the rails instance itself will not serve static assets. So perhaps you're running it in production and that's why it can't see the assets? I can't think of any other reason with the information provided so far.

Comment: I'm running it in development mode. It's not that it can't see the assets, it's that there aren't any there. I can't even find the images that the blue theme was using.

Comment: Spree is a plugin, all of those files are sitting in the directory for the gem itself, not in the app you add it to.  To change them you just override them in your app.

Comment: I guess the real problem I'm having is I don't know the names of the files I want to skin or where to find them. Like in the spree tutorial, I know there's a file at app/views/spree/checkout/registration.html.erb, but how do I know the file name, directory, and what's inside of it? Where are the gem files located? I downloaded a copy of spree from github, and the files didn't seem to be in the right locations or have the right names.

Answer (score 0):

The way I over came this is to download the main spree gem, via github.com, look where the images are located then creating the images I wanted to override in my local app/assets directory with the same path run:

```
rake assets:precompile:nondigest
```

restart webrick/pow or any other web server you are running and voila!

Comment: Hey, thank you! I appreciate your response, but what about the views and such? Is there any easy way to view them?

Comment: If you download the gem browse to core/app/view/spree and all your views will be there ready for the taking :) should you wish to amend these simply copy them to your local project app/views/spree and the ones in your project will override the ones in the gem. hope this clears it up :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're not really familiar with how gems work. As people here have said, these are not going to automatically show up in your core app directory, but the gemfile and running bundle install knows how to reference them.

So you need to find those gems to figure out the file names, as you said. If you want to view the gemfiles run this command in the terminal:

```
$ bundle open spree_frontend
```

If you get this error:

`To open a bundled gem, set $EDITOR or $BUNDLER_EDITOR`

then you haven't set up the editor, so do this:

```
export BUNDLER_EDITOR=sublime
```

Then redo the bundle open command. This should open the spree_frontend directory which will let you investigate the file names/paths and the assets. If you want to change an entire template, you need to create that file matching its name and path exactly as it is in the spree gem (spree/layouts/spree_application.html.erb for example) then when you edit it your rails app will render the code in your core app directory thus overriding the spree gem.

That make sense?